# What is contained in a published ASP.net project?

Tags: c#

I developed a site in asp.net using C# as the language. 
I have debugged it and no more errors can be found and can also view the page from a browser.
I would like to host this site and direct a client to it for demo purposes but am having a problem each time I publish my site. The publishing only does away with all my **.aspx.cs** files but I don't see any **.exe** file that I can install or send to my hosting provider.

I would like to know if this what I am experiencing is normal or there are settings I need to do in my visual studio 2013 ultimate edition for these tasks to be performed?

Kindly advise me on the way forward

Comment: When you published your app? Do you see a publish folder in your project?

Comment: The publish project will only include only the markup (`.aspx`) and all other required files. All the `.aspx.cs` and `.cs` are compiled as `.dll` and available under `bin` folder of your application. All you need to do is to set up a IIS website on the target server and deploy the published code.

Comment: @Dennis R, I can see the .dll in place of .aspx.cs files....so is that all I need before I can upload it to hosting site?

Comment: Yes, the published project should contain everything what you need to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET applications (not "ASP.NET websites") are compiled into a `.dll` file in your `bin` folder, which is then deployed on to the server.

Your `.aspx`/`.cshtml1` files reference compiled classes and types contained within this DLL, thus eliminating the need for source files.

Comment: thank you. so when this is done, does it mean my site is published and can be uploaded to the hosting site?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "published".

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any .exe files, you need to deploy your project to a web server, like IIS. Check out [this link](http://blog.pluralsight.com/windows-server-2008-iis7).